# DOCKER does not run manage.py

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

somebody can explain why docker does not wanna run Django server

Thats my structure of project:

```
app
  bankproject
      env
      docker-compose.yml
      Dockerfile
      manage.py  
      requirements.txt
```

There is my file Docker:

```
    # pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.0-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . /app
```

and my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
```

Actually in folder env I have file .env.dev
and it is consist :

```
DEBUG=1
SECRET_KEY=foo
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
```

The mistake I got :

web_1  | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
app_web_1 exited with code 2

Comment: After `COPY . /app`, add `RUN pwd && ls -lah .` command and see what is the current location and whether `manage.py` exists?

Answer (score 0):

I think you set your working directory wrongly in your Dockerfile if i am not mistaken it should look like this:

```
# set work directory
WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app
```

Comment: edited, like you said , but still does not working(((

Comment: That won't help either, since `manage.py` is in the subdirectory, so being in `/app` doesn't help ...

Comment: this is just another guest looking at your file structure but i think you should start by cd into the bankproject directory. Then run python manage.py, because ur currenty in your root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your `volumes:` are overwriting the image content with arbitrary content from the host.  When the directory layout doesn't match, it hides the `/app/manage.py` script you copied in.

You should delete the `command:` and `volumes:` lines from your `docker-compose.yml` file.  (You'll also have to put a corresponding `CMD` in the Dockerfile; `ENTRYPOINT` is optional and you should omit it here.)  That leaves you with

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: ./
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
```

If you look around with your current setup, you should see two things.  If you `docker-compose run web sh`, I'd expect you'll see the `/app` directory is totally empty; if you look around on your host system, there will be an empty `app` directory next to the `docker-compose.yml` and other top-level files.  These are created by the `volumes:` directive you have, since it points at a non-existent directory (the `./app` part).